# Confusing about Global forward and Action mapping

Tags: struts, struts-1, struts-config

for example

```
    <global-forwards>
      <forward name="welcome"  path="/Welcome.do"/>
    </global-forwards>

    <action-mappings>
      <action path="/Welcome" forward="/welcomeStruts.jsp"/>
    </action-mappings>
```

My question is:
When client requests Welcome.do page, the global forward will map the /welcome.do page with the name attribute "welcome". Then in action-mapping it will map between the name in forward tag with the path in action tag so it will know that it should forward to the welcomeStruts.jsp file.

 Am I correct?

If not, how can it determine the correct mapping between user's request *.do to the corresponding jsp file?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not correct. When a request comes in, Struts tries to map the URL or the request with the path of an action. Forwards are not used at this stage.

When the action returns a forward name, Struts first looks for a forward with this name in the forwards of the action, and if not found, it looks in the global forwards.

Comment: just 1 more thing, i dont understand how the requests will be mapped with the corresponding action controlles, i tried finding the mapping in web.xml and struts-config.xml but i didn't see that part. Can you explain it ? Thank you

Comment: Usually, the web.xml has a mapping for the URL pattern `*.do` to the Struts servlet. Then the Struts servlet removes .do from the path of the request, and finds the action that has the resulting path.

Comment: so do you mean that it will happend at this part of the struts-config.xml file :<action path="/AddSelCommand" 
  name="SASSpecialistRepFormBean"
  type="actions.AddSelCommand"
  scope="request">
  <forward name="representative" path="/WEB-INF/jsp/SpecialistRepresentativeAddSelection.jsp"> 
  </forward>
  </action>

Comment: I mean that is the request path is /AddSelCommand.do, Struts will execute this action, because its path is /AddSelCommand.